# Codeigniter template-Fetching data from database: 404 error

Tags: database, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, templates

I am trying to make a user page where I can display a table with users' data taken from database. When I run the file I got a 404 error. I would be very grateful if you could take a look into my code.

display_user.php

```
<?php  
   class display_user extends CI_Controller  
   {  
      public function index()  
      {  
         //load the database  
         $this->load->database();  
         //load the model  
         $this->load->model('DisplayModel');  
         //load the method of model  
         $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
         //return the data in view  
         $this->load->view('user_view', $data);  
      }  
      public function signin()
    {
        //$this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('user_view');
        //$this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }

    public function validate()
    {   $this->load->helper('email');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('admin_model');

        $query=$this->DisplayModel->signin_control();

        if($query)
            {   $admin_id = $this->DisplayModel->get_admin_id_from_username();
                $admin    = $this->DisplayModel->get_admin($employee_id);

                $data = array('id'=>$employee_id, 'email' =>$this->input->post('email') , 'is_logged_in'=>true);

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);

                $this->load->view('admin_view',$employee);

            }
        else
            {   

                $this->index();
            }
    }
    public function signup()
    {

        $this->load->view('view_signup',array('error' => ' ' ));

    }

   }  
?>
```

DisplayModel.php

```
<?php  
   class DisplayModel extends CI_Model  
   {  
      function __construct()  
      {  
         // Call the Model constructor  
         parent::__construct();  
      }  
      //we will use the select function  
      public function select()  
      {  
         //data is retrive from this query  
         $query = $this->db->get('employee');  
         return $query;  
      }  
       function signin_control()
     {
        $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('password'));
        $query=$this->db->get('employee');
        if($query->num_rows()==1) 
            return $query;
     }
    public function get_employee_id_from_username() 
     {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('employee');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        return $this->db->get()->row('id');

    }
     public function get_employee($employee_id) 
    {

        $this->db->from('employee');
        $this->db->where('id', $employee_id);
        return $this->db->get()->row();

    }
}
```

user_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kreatx</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>


      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
        <img src="../../images/user.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User" width="304" height="236">
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome <strong>$employee_emer<strong>!</h1>

      <hr>

   <table border="1">  
      <tbody>  
         <tr> 
      <td><strong>Employee Id</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Password</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Employee Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Employee Surname</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Department ID</strong></td>
    </tr> 
     <?php  
         foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
         {  
            ?><tr> 
         <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->username;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->password;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->employee_emer;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->mbiemer;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->adresa;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->id_departament;?></td>
      </tr>     
      <?php }  
         ?> 

      </tbody>  
   </table>  


           </div>     
          </br>


      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">

     <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/display_user/index"; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" >Update Profile </a>
    </br></br></br>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/chat/index"; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" > Chat </a>
     </br></br></br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p><a href="http://www.kreatx.com/">Kreatx</a></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you run the file? which file do you run?

Comment: localhost/ci_intro/index.php/display_user/index